# Convention for analytic continuation of Binet formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, complex-numbers

**Background**:

There is an interesting pattern in certain square-roots of complex numbers when split into their component parts:

$ \sqrt{1+2i} = \phi^{1/2} + i\phi^{-1/2}$

$ \sqrt{4+2i} = \phi^{3/2} + i\phi^{-3/2}$

$ \sqrt{11+2i} = \phi^{5/2} + i\phi^{-5/2}$

where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. The numbers $\{1, 4, 11,\cdots\}$ are the odd Lucas numbers $\{L_1, L_3, L_5,\cdots\}$. This seems to be a straight-forward generalization of the "square expansion" formula listed on [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasNumber.html)'s article on Lucas numbers for half-integer $n$, giving $\sqrt{L_n + 2i} = L_{n/2}$ using Binet's formula for the Lucas numbers,

$ L_n = \phi^n + (-\phi)^{-n} $.

In fact, this formula would hold much more generally if one were to define a generalization of Binet's formula to

$ L(z) = \phi^z + e^{-i\pi z}\phi^{-z} $

giving a general identity $L(z) = \sqrt{L(2z) + 2e^{-i\pi z}}$. Similar identities would hold for a Fibonacci function $F(z)$. However, Mathworld also defines the analytic continuation of the Binet formulas as

$ F(z) = \frac{\phi^z - \cos(\pi z)\phi^{-z}}{\sqrt{5}} $

which would imply a definition for the Lucas one as

$ L(z) = \phi^z + \cos(\pi z)\phi^{-z} $.

This would seem to break these identities, as $\cos(\pi/2)=0$. This leads to my question:

**Question**:

Why is the analytic continuation of $F(z)$ defined using $\cos(\pi z)$ instead of $e^{-i\pi z}$, which would seem to interfere with some of the before-mentioned square-root identities? I assume whoever defined it that way had some intention in mind!

Comment: Hi, I have not yet taken a course in complex analysis, but Matt Parker has a rather nice video on this exact topic, though it doesn't contain the technical details you're looking for - I just think it's interesting. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghxQA3vvhsk)

Comment: I think this video does answer my question actually, thank you for linking it! Based on his linked Geogebra pages, I think they used the version discussed here and not the version with just the cosine. Thank you!